# Do you need to stop in progress actions in viewDidUnload or dealloc?

Tags: objective-c

I have seen code such as the following to stop in progress actions in viewDidUnload or dealloc.  Is it really necessary?

[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely necessary in `dealloc`, but only if you previously sent a `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` message (or one of its variants) to `self`. Otherwise, your deallocated instance will receive the message after the specified delay and crash.

It's context sensitive whether it's required in `vidDidUnload`. The requested selector is more-than-likely no longer needed given that the controller no longer has a view, but you never know.